# How to remove marker and paint from wall?

Tags: cleaning, home, adhesive, paint

Children have a bad habit to remove any where with permanent stuff like markers and paint. It is not easy to remove that stuff from wall. It looks so ugly. How can I remove these things from the wall?

Comment: Paint over it, and don't allow the children to use these things without supervision. Or turn it into a cave drawing, embrace it as art from a beloved child.. And paint over it when they want a girlfriend/boyfriend or it becomes some sort of embarassment to them :)

Comment: "Wall" is a very vague term - what material are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In order to remove Mark and Paint from wall:**

In order to remove the marker

1.Magic Eraser 
2.Wall Cleaner (Used for cleaning walls prior to painting)
3.Painting over the marker

In order to remove Paint

1. Paint the wall