# How to remove paint from floor?

Tags: cleaning, home

As we painted our home there are some Mate Enamel paint spots left on the tiled floor. Kindly guide me how to remove such undesired spots.

I tried some acid but the spots still remain. How to remove these spots properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove marker and paint from wall?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/19856/how-to-remove-marker-and-paint-from-wall)

Comment: “Floor” and “paint” are very vague terms. The answers will depend on what material you floor is made of and what type of paint you used. Please [edit] your post with details.

Answer (score 3):

I'd let it dry fully (however long the can says) then remove it mechanically (use a sharp knife or scalpel under the edge) to remove most of the paint and then a mild abrasive cleaner, like one of those sponges with the green scrubbing material on one side, on the rest

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Caius Jard's answer, I would try to use [glass scrapper](https://www.google.com/search?q=glass+scraper&rlz=1C1GCEU_enHR819HR819&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq1JPjupzfAhUCI1AKHa_rAYsQ_AUIDigB&biw=1920&bih=938) if everything else fails. It should be easier than scrapping with a knife.

Also, you can try with a [heat gun](https://www.4x4community.co.za/forum/showthread.php/94445-Removing-enamel-paint) or buy [enamel paint remover](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002MR8AIS).

Comment: It's a good call that on tiles, heat could be used to burn the paint without affecting the tiles much

Answer (score 0):

The normal method to remove paint of most kinds is to use turpentine, kerosene, white spirit. Try those, leave it a few minutes, wipe off.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turpentine

Answer (score 0):

Someone once told me that Baby oil will soften dried enamel paint and lift it off to the point where a plastic dish scouring pad lightly applied will remove it from the floor.  I believe cooking oil will work as well. I believe the reason for this is because the paint is oil based.